# Layer 2 how to read tx data

Tags: go-ethereum, layer-2

How would i be able to read TX data from layer 2, same as layer 1? From my understanding geth/erigon cant see this data. Would i need to run a validator node?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply rely on a web3 provider API like Infura of Alchemy. They provide access to all sorts of networks, including most mainstream layer-2 solutions. Then, could couple the API of your choice with an Ethereum JavaScript library like EthersJS to be able to write scripts to read and process data fetched from the blockchain.